# Why are Lie Groups so "rigid"?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, lie-groups

This is probably a naive question, but here goes. To motivate my question, I'll consider a unit circle in $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R^2$. This is a compact Lie group equipped with the usual exponential map. However, any deformation no matter how smooth of the unit circle makes it lose the group closure property (say under complex multiplication) and it ceases to be a Lie group.

My question is why is this so? How does one prove, for example, that it is not possible to  have a Lie group which is an ellipse (or any other shape) in $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R^2$? Why is it not possible to have a "complex multiplication like" binary operator that takes two points on an ellipse and returns a third without affecting other group properties?

Thanks.

Comment: Er, what do you mean by "unit circle in $Z$?"

Comment: @AdamHughes: perhaps, complex plane is meant

Comment: Sorry, I meant the complex plane C, of course

Comment: Of course it is possible to turn an ellipse into a Lie group, since ellipses are diffeomorphic to circles.

Comment: I mean, this is sort of a weasely question, you may as well ask why **sets** are so rigid, any map at all that's not a bijection on the set totally throws it into a different set. If you're just worried about manifold and group structure you're taking a specific set where the group structure is perhaps most natural, but it's somewhat unfair to requires that it be literally the same set if you want any kind of useful notion of equivalence. This is part of the reason why many people like manifolds to be intrinsic rather than embedded.

Comment: They seem rigid to you because you stuck them in a rigid ambient space. Pick any diffeomorphism from a simple Jordan curve to the circle and define multiplication on the curve as multiplication on the circle under this map. Now it's a compact Lie group.

Comment: Thanks! I see why my question was  "unreasonable".